# Perplexing issue with simple coroutine in Lua

Tags: lua, runtime-error, coroutine

I'm learning Lua and trying to create a simple coroutine. In Lua 5.1, the code below gives the error: "attempt to yield across metamethod/C-call boundary." I've read about that limitation and I can't see how it applies to my code. I tried it in Lua 5.2 and got "attempt to yield from outside a coroutine," which is equally confusing to me. I'm sure the answer will be embarrassingly obvious!

```
output = {}
done = false

function mainLoop()
  while not done do
    if co == nil then
      co = coroutine.create(subLoop())
    elseif coroutine.status(co) == "suspended" then
      print(output[k])
      coroutine.resume(co)
    elseif coroutine.status(co) == "dead" then
      done = true
    end
  end
end

function subLoop()
  for k=1, 20 do
    table.insert(output, "This is line " .. k .. " of the test output")
    coroutine.yield()
  end
end

mainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `subLoop`

```
    if co == nil then
      co = coroutine.create(subLoop())
```

instead of passing it to `coroutine.create`

```
    if co == nil then
      co = coroutine.create(subLoop)
```

This results in you attempting to `yield` from the main state / (not-really-)coroutine, which gives errors with varying descriptions across versions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! But if you don't call the function, can you still pass arguments to it somehow?

Comment: Well, you pass them to `coroutine.resume` and they fall out of `coroutine.yield` (or come in as normal arguments on the first `resume`). So `f = coroutine.create( function( ... )  local args = { ... } ; while true do  args = { coroutine.yield( table.unpack( args ) ) }  end  end )` will simply return what you pass in. `resume( f, "foo" ) --> "foo"`, `resume( f, 23, 42 ) --> 23, 42`, and so on.